# how to remove const from member function template type signature?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, g++, metaprogramming

I'm working on some C++ type system stuff, and I'm having a problem removing const-ness from a member function for use with function trait classes.  What is really toubling here is that this works fine with G++, but MSVC10 fails to handle the partial specialization correctly, and I don't know if one of these compilers actually has a bug here.

The question here is, what is the correct way to remove the const qualifier from the member function in such a way that I can get a function type signature?

Take the following code sample:

```
  #include <iostream>

  template<typename T> struct RemovePointer { typedef T Type; };
  template<typename T> struct RemovePointer<T*> { typedef T Type; };
  template<typename R,typename T> struct RemovePointer<R (T::*)> { typedef R Type; };

  class A {
  public:
     static int StaticMember() { return 0; }
     int Member() { return 0; }
     int ConstMember() const { return 0; }
  };

  template<typename T> void PrintType(T arg) {
     std::cout << typeid(typename RemovePointer<T>::Type).name() << std::endl;
  }

  int main()
  {
     PrintType(&A::StaticMember);
     PrintType(&A::Member);
     PrintType(&A::ConstMember); // WTF?
  }
```

All three of these PrintType statements should print the same thing.  MSVC10 prints the following:

```
int __cdecl(void)
int __cdecl(void)
int (__cdecl A::*)(void)const __ptr64
```

g++ prints this (which is the expected result):

```
FivE
FivE
FivE
```

Comment: _"What is the correct way to remove the const qualifier from the member function in such a way that I can get a function type signature?"_ The const-qualification of a member function is part of its signature.

Comment: I don't know what you want this for, but the signature of a static and an non-static member functions **are** different. I find the output of the first two lines being equal worse than the fact that the third is different. What is it that you really want to solve?

Comment: The name() from the typeid is entirely implementation specific. How can you say which one is right or wrong?

Comment: @BoPersson You are missing the point.

Comment: The type that GCC prints is wrong (basing on demangling done by `c++filt`). The third should be a `int() const` but it says it's a `int()`.

Comment: Mind explaining what I am missing? The standard doesn't say what strings should be printed, and you say that the strings are wrong?

Comment: @aschepler it's a semantic match, not a syntactic match. Like `T*` matches `void(*)()` with `T == void()`, a `R C::*` matches `void(C::*)()` with `R == void()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the TypeTraits.h of the loki library by Alexandrescu. 
It provides a generic way to strip qualifiers, like const.

http://loki-lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/loki-lib/loki/include/loki/TypeTraits.h?view=markup

When I have some philosophical issues with meta programming c++ meta programming I tend to look in Modern c++ design if there is an answer for my whereabouts.

Comment: This solved my problem.  Not in the way that I would have preferred, but it demonstrates that I can't do what I need with a few lines of code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This one would help:

```
template<typename R,typename T> struct RemovePointer<R (T::*)() const> { typedef R Type; };
```

Note that you probably want add `()` in previous line, too (otherwise it would match both pointers-to-members and pointers-to-functions):

```
template<typename R,typename T> struct RemovePointer<R (T::*)()> { typedef R Type; };
```

Comment: That actually doesn't work.  This causes R to match the return type, not the function type.

Comment: I see... then I doubt it should be compilable: why `R` in `R (T::*)` should be "function type"?

Comment: I’m not sure what’s up with this syntax (I’ve never used pointers to member function) but this works. Funny – I was convinced that `R (T const::*)` should work (since it’s the type `T` that’s supposed to be `const`) but that doesn’t work …

Comment: @Konrad If you have a `void f() const { }` in a class, then this defines a member with type `void() const`. Therefor, if you take a member pointer of class C, you get a `void (C::*)() const`, or expressed in another way, a `R C::*` where `R` is a `void() const`. This is not the same as saying that `R` is a `U const` where `U` is `void()`: There are no const function types. The const at the end of a function type doesn't make a function "non-modifiable" or such.

Comment: It's also not the same as waying that `R` is `void()` and `C` is `const U`. What you have is a member pointer of class `C`. Not of class type `const U`. The member has a specific type, not the class.

Comment: @Johannes: I’m confused. I thought that in `R (T::*)` the type of the surrounding class is given by `T` and that `R` is the function’s return value. Isn’ that correct? Like I said, I have never so far used member function pointers.

Comment: @Konrad you are confusing `R (T::*)(parameters)` with `R T::*` (or equivalently with a binding parenthesis `R (T::*)`). The former is the type of a member function pointer explicitly written manually (comparable when declaring a function pointer and saying `void (*f)();`). The latter is the type of a member function pointer expressed by a function type `R` (comparable to declaring the function pointer by `typedef void R(); R *f;`).

Comment: @Johannes ok. So in `R T::*` we have `R` = the type of the function. Now, what is `T`? Still the surrounding type of the member function? That syntax is just FUBAR.

Comment: @Konrad it's very logical. `identity<int>::type T::*` is a member data pointer. And `identity<void()>::type T::*` is a member function pointer. `T` is always the class of which the pointer is a member (`identity<T>::type` denoting the type `T`).

Answer (score 1):

`typeid(...).name()` returns an implementation-defined string. It could be a compiler-mangled symbol, or a poem written by Jon Skeet. Please don't rely on it to do anything useful.

It also seems odd to want to take "const" off it; the function *is* `const`, so why don't you want that in the resulting string?

I have no idea why you're expecting, or seeing, "FIvE". I can't see anything like it in your code.

Comment: `FivE` is a mangled type.  Using the GNU demangler, `c++filt FivE` gives `int ()()`.